# How to add multiple raw elements in a array without allocating any memory?

Tags: java

Is there any way to add multiple raw elements to an Vector without allocating any memory (in a single statement)?

```
new Vector(1,2,2,2,2,2,2,3)
new Vector().addAll(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1)
```

Comment: How can you save anything without allocating memory?

Comment: The compiler could internally handle it

Comment: You could write your own addAll method that takes an array of integers and adds them to a Vector.  addAll(vector, 1, 1, 1, etc.);

Answer (score 1):

```
class NewVector extends Vector
{
/*New*/Vector <E> addAll(E... args)
{
for(E arg:args) this.add(arg);
return this;
}
//[...Your expectations...]
}
```